# Java IF Statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to write a Java program with a bunch of IF Statements. I'm confused about what it's actually supposed to look like. Could someone pleaaaase please give me an example with the question below, or something similar? Do IF Statements require a System.out.print for every variable in order for it to compile?

// Thank you soooo much!!!

Use a nested if to test the following conditions:
    If a boolean variable called sale is set to true, do the following:
        If the int variable price is less than 50, the double variable 
discount is set to 0.01.
If the int variable price is 50 or greater, the double variable 
discount is set to 0.02.

This is the code I wrote for this, but I don't think it's correct....

```
boolean sale;
 int price;
 double discount;

 System.out.print("Please Enter Sale ");
  sale = keyboard.nextBoolean();

  if (sale == true)
    if  (price <= 50)
    discount = 0.01;

    else (price >= 50)
    discount = 0.02;
```

Comment: "Do IF Statements require a System.out.print for every variable in order for it to compile?" Nope, and it's not clear why you'd think that. I would strongly advise you to use braces around them though. You say you don't think your code is correct... what's going wrong at the moment?

Comment: The code doesn't compile because of the condition on the else statement.  If that were removed it would work fine, although yes the braces around the if statement blocks would make it much clearer.

Comment: You should really read a tutorial about if statements, like the [nuts and bolts tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Comment: Yeah, because this is such a small example it's pretty easy to spot the problem, but even for these kinds of examples you should include the actual error you're seeing in the question - that way your question can be useful to others with the same issue in the future, which is what we aim for on SO.

Comment: I suggest reading a  Java basics book/website or going through a course and learning basics (Codecademy is a good, free way to learn language syntax). Basic syntax is covered in these.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if (sale == true)
```

is the same as

```
if (sale)
```

and if this is not true

```
if  (price <= 50)
```

then you know the price > 50 so there is no need to check again.

```
if (sale)
   if  (price <= 50)
       discount = 0.01;
   else // price > 50
       discount = 0.02;
```

Some people prefer using { and } though I think using the formatter in your IDE  (which you should use) makes this redundant. Using braces looks like

```
if (sale) {
   if  (price <= 50) {
       discount = 0.01;
   } else { // price > 50
       discount = 0.02;
   }
}
```

another way to write this is to use ?: which shortens the code

```
if (sale)
   discount = price <= 50 ? 0.01 : 0.02;
```

Note: since the `discount` has to set I would write it like this

```
double discount = sale 
                ? price <= 50 ? 0.01 : 0.02
                : Double.NaN;
```

Comment: The ternary operator option is the best choice for simple conditions like this. Clean and clear.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the gist of it, but two corrections.

'else' is simply the base case if no 'if' statement in that if/else block returns true, so you don't need another conditional like you're doing with

```
else (price >= 50)
```

as

```
else
```

does what you're trying to do.

If you wanted a second conditional, you'd use 'else if.' Example:

```
if(price < 50) { //If price is less than 50.
    //Do something.
}else if(price == 50) { //If price is equal to 50.
    //Do something else.
}else{ //Price isn't less than or equal to 50, so it has to be greater than 50.
    //Do something else...else.
}
```

The second correction is with

```
if  (price <= 50)
```

This is checking if the price is less than OR equal to 50. That's not the goal of your program as you described it.

> If the int variable price is less than 50

Answer (score 0):

First of all, an if statement in java is the same as an in statement in english. 
English: "If it is cold, i wear a jacket"

Java:

```
if(cold){
   //wear jacket
}
```

so the if statement consist of two parts a condition and a reaction. If the condition is true, the reaction performs.

```
if(condition){
  reaction
}
```

On the other side the System.out.println() is for you programm to speak with you (write something as an output).
So the if statement and the System.out.println() are unrelated.

You are using a special form of the if statements (one without brackets) in this case only the next command after the if statement is taken as reaction

```
if(condition)
   reaction
no reaction anymore
```

as a beginner it is better to always set brackets

the else statement is always an alternative and used like this:

```
if(condition){
    reaction
}else{
    alternative reaction
}
```

the else statement is active if the condition is false. So either "reaction" or "alternative reaction" are run.

then your code would look like this:

```
   boolean sale;
   int price;
   double discount;

   System.out.print("Please Enter Sale ");
   sale = keyboard.nextBoolean();

   if(sale == true){
       if(price <= 50){
           discount = 0.01;
       } else {
           discount = 0.02;
       }
   }
```

and now with the brackets, we can see the problem of your code. The else